# Closing UIImageView using tags

Tags: ios, uiimageview

I am defining an UIImageView like this:

```
UIImageView *backgroundView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"fondo1"]];

backgroundView.tag = 7;
```

Then on another method, I try to dismiss the UIView using following method, which is called from a button action:

```
-(void) closeSideTasks {
    for (UIImageView *subview in [self.view subviews]) {
        if (subview.tag == 7) {
            [subview removeFromSuperview];
        }
    }
}
```

But this is throwing an exception:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[ToDoItemsTableViewController closeSideTasks:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
```

Where is my error?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is the most frequently asked iOS programming question and the questioner has not bothered to discover that fact.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you are calling method with an argument (note closeSideTasks: the semicolon) the compiler expects you to receive an argument but finds no method for that. The method you have defined does not accept arguments.

If this is a selector that u are using from button action, try defining it as -(IBaction)closesidetasks:(id)sender. 
And implementing it as same.

Answer (score 1):

The error, as the error message plainly tells you, is that your button is sending `closeSideTasks:` even though the method is named `closeSideTasks` (without the colon).

Answer (score 0):

Use this instead

```
-(void) closeSideTasks {
                UIImageView * backgroundView = (UIImageView *)[self.view viewWithTag:7];
                [backgroundView removeFromSuperview];
    }
```